# KeyError Exception when import data in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, python-import, keyerror

I am using Cassandra 2.2 and I created table 'teste':

> CREATE TABLE teste(
>      idflight UUID,
>      unique_carrier text,
>      taiNumber text,
>      airTime int,
>      depDelay int,
>      PRIMARY KEY (unique_carrier, depDelay, idflight)
>      );

Then I tried to import data from a CSV file using COPY FROM command:

> COPY teste(idflight, unique_carrier, tailNumber, airTime, depDelay) FROM 'out.csv' WITH HEADER = true AND DELIMITER = ',';

When running this command occurs the following error:

```js
Process ImportProcess-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2306, in run
    cqltypes = [table_meta.columns[name].typestring for name in self.columns]
KeyError: 'tailnumber'
Process ImportProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2306, in run
    cqltypes = [table_meta.columns[name].typestring for name in self.columns]
KeyError: 'tailnumber'
Process ImportProcess-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2306, in run
    cqltypes = [table_meta.columns[name].typestring for name in self.columns]
KeyError: 'tailnumber'
```

What should I do to correct this problem?

Comment: Not sure it's only in the SO question, but there's a typo in the table definition where the column name is `taiNumber` (missing the `l`). The other thing you can try is to use all lower case column names.

Comment: Thank you, had not noticed that. I don't know if that was the error reason  but I drop column family and create a new and everything has worked.